# Can we detect whether ad is preroll, midroll or postroll from a VAST XML in js?

Tags: javascript, flowplayer, vast

I am using flowplayer [vast](http://demos.flowplayer.org/ads/vast.html) to show ads in a video. But the problem which I face is that the actual video plays for some milliseconds before the preroll ad video starts .

I was thinking of reading the XML first to detect whether there is any preroll ad video. And if there is, than I can pause the actual video.

I don't know how to detect whether the ad in VAST XML is having a preroll ad and whether that ad is a video ad.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard VAST XML Schema element, which could tell the player when to play the Linear (video) - you decide when to play the ad. (Pre-Roll, Mid-Roll, Post-Roll, Whatever)

To read the VAST XML first, you would need a fully qualified VAST parser for all VAST versions. This parser needs to be able to handle VAST Wrappers as well. After reading potentially multiple VASTs, the player/plugin makes a decision for one or more Ads to get played.
 I guess, your approach will not work if you're not willing to implement a new VAST/VPAID plugin for flowplayer or even a complete player.

So, your player resp. the VAST plugin does this for you. But there is still a problem with the actual video is starting before the pre-roll starts, right?

Two potential issues:

1. You probably missed something in your configuration, like *autoPlay: true/false* or an *event* which you should catch.
2. The player/plugin is buggy and you need to find another player/plugin

If you're still interested to find informations about the VAST content or if the VAST contains a video resource, you will find it at:

> #### VAST XML
>
> / VAST / Ad / InLine / Creatives / Creative / Linear `*` / MediaFiles / MediaFile
>
> #### Attributes
>
> **type** resp. mime-type (VAST 1-3) and/or 
>   **apiFramework** (VAST 2-3)
>
> `* if there is no Linear element, than there is no Video`

**Note 1**: Multiple Ads allowed
**Note 2**: A few things added to VAST 4.0, please have a look yourself.

But as I said, this is insufficient, 'cause you need to parse VAST Wrappers as well.

Further informations you can find within the specs: [VAST 4](http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/VAST_4-0_2016-01-21.pdf), [VAST 3](http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VASTv3_0.pdf), [VAST 2](http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/VAST-2_0-FINAL.pdf), [VAST 1](http://www.iab.net/media/file/VAST_1_11_FINAL.pdf)

Hope this was helpfull somehow and have a nice day.